# Simple Function Not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been messing with this function and got it to work when I had it set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var num1 = document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0];

            num1.onmouseover = (function(){
                var changeIt = document.getElementsByClassName("topb")[0];
                if (changeIt.style.visibility === "hidden") {
                    changeIt.style.visibility = "visible";
                }else {
                changeIt.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

My problem is that I'm currently trying to make it a reusable function, for multiple variables. When I try and set it up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            var num1 = document.getElementsByClassName("top")[0];
            var num1b = document.getElementsByClassName("topb")[0];

            function myFunc(x){
                if(x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
                    x.style.visibility = "visible";
                }else {
                    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
                }};

            num1.onmouseover= myFunc(num1b);
```

It won't work. I'm sure it's some syntax or scope issue? Not quite sure I've been researching it and can pin it down). Does anyone out there have a suggestion? Thank you so much in advance. 
PS my CSS and HTML are fine, seeing that I have had them working with the previous function set up.

Comment: You called your function immediately and assigned its result.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding that. I've been reading on immediately invoked functions.. should I put it in a variable instead?

Comment: Also as a side note; you should also consider reducing the number of ways you are approaching your issues.  You have a document ready, which means you are including jQuery, but then you use the native getElementsByClassName methods, rather than using jQuery.  Then you use the inline onmouseover property rather than using the addEventListener or the jQuery on() method.  It would be more readable if you picked one approach to the issues and stuck with it.

Comment: Right...if you are loading jQuery.js might as well take advantage of it's *"write less"* code approach

Comment: Right, sorry about that. I read a book that kind of mixed the two and am having a hard time keeping it consistent. Thanks!

Comment: I do agree with the one approach to keep things consistent. Eventually you'll come to despise inline event handlers. *one of us, one of us*

Comment: @JoeLinnemeier It's not really an issue, just something to keep in mind.  Usually when developers read code that switches between different approaches to problems, we look at it trying to figure out **why** it was done that way.  If there isn't a concrete reason, it can wind up spending more time that you need to on a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning the *result* of the function to the mouseover event, not the function itself.  Since it doesn't return anything, it is being assigned to `undefined` and therefore having no effect.

Since your function is within the scope that has access to the `num1b` variable, you do not need to pass it as a parameter.

Try this instead:

```
function myFunc(){
  if(num1b.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    num1b.style.visibility = "visible";
  }else {
    num1b.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};

num1.onmouseover = myFunc;//assign the FUNCTION not the result by not including parenthesis
```

or, to make use of jQuery to reduce code, you could simply do this:

```
$(".top").mouseover(function () {
  $(".topb").toggle();
});
```

mouseover will cause this to fire every time the mouse moves one pixel over the element, so this could result in rapid flashing, you may want to use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to have better control over this behavior.

Comment: Yeah. That example is similar to the first one I tried, which worked. But, what I want to do is make it so that I can use this function on many different variables. So, I would want an X where the "num1b" is in the example above, if that makes sense.

Comment: That does help, however, to limit the code I have to write

Comment: See the jquery edit -- the `toggle` method basically does what your function does, so you wouldn't even need a wrapper function if you went that route

Comment: @Taplar I agree, I just wanted to have a 1-to-1 reproduction of the original code but in jquery.  I did mentioned `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as better alternatives.

Comment: @JoeLinnemeier The question I have is in what way do you plan to pass the parameter into the event handler?  Events get an [event object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_event.asp) (or [jquery event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)) passed in as the first parameter so you'd have to use perhaps the `event.target` to figure out what element you wanted to toggle visibility on.

Comment: I copy and pasted your jquery code in my page and it's not working, I have no idea why.Also,  I'll have to read more about event objects to answer the question, I think. But, the event.target method seems like a great idea.

Comment: @JoeLinnemeier You'll probably still want that jquery snippet inside your `$(document).ready` method to ensure the elements have rendered before the event handler is assigned